# json error in virto commerce while importing data

Tags: json, virtocommerce

I am getting  the following error while importing data in virtocommerce

> Error resolving type specified in JSON
>   'VirtoCommerce.StoreModule.Web.Security.StoreSelectedScope,
>   VirtoCommerce.StoreModule.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Path
>   'Users[5].Roles[1].Permissions[0].AssignedScopes.$values[0].$type',
>   line 101, position 175.  Could not load assembly
>   'VirtoCommerce.StoreModule.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Virto Commerce Manager not worked with IIS Express. You should configure IIS application to working with manager as writing here  [source Code Getting Started](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started)

Answer (score 0):

If you are following this steps

http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started

when you can see this

[image]

Don't login now. You have login after when you see after completing

***Right click on VirtoCommerce.Storefront project and select View > View in Browser or use your preferred way to start the web project.***

if you view this you can see

[image]

If you see this then login in admin and import store. and brows your store